# Problem feeding an ESP8266 and RGB 12V led strip from single source

Tags: dc-dc-converter, esp8266, led-strip, 12v, nodemcu

I have an issue while was trying to feed an ESP8266 nodemcu v3 lolin and a RBG 12V led strip from the same source. When I try to use the same source, I am unable to access this ESP8266 webpage, as well as use the button to turn this strip on and off, but it shows that is receiving power as well as the RGB led strip. I am using a power supply of 12V 5A.

This is the schematic:

[image]

What I have done:

- If I disconnect the 12V feed sent to that led strip, I am able to use that ESP8266 without problem.
- If I feed that ESP8266 from my computer, without using Vin from the DC DC converter, and leave the rest of all the connections, I am able to use that ESP and control the led strip as expected.
- If I feed that strip directly without using the DC DC converter input pins, and feed this ESP with USB, it works also has expected.

For a better understanding here it goes in pratice what I have:

[image]

Anyone knows what can be happening, and how to solve it?

Comment: Throw a few 1000 uF caps at it? One at each of the boards.

Comment: And is the ground between the in - and out - on the regulator connected? And what if you use a different 12v supply?

Comment: When you say "throw a few caps", you mean adding those between IN+ and the led strip VCC, and other between OUT+ and Vin of this ESP? Between IN+ and OUT+ there is only the DC-DC converter LM2596, who doesnt have a ground connector. There are only those 4 connections that I have mentioned in the schematic. I have used two 12V power supplies, with different max of current (one with 2A and another with 5A), but same outcome.

Comment: The caps would go as close as possible to the V+ and Gnd of each board. So one at the protoboard, one at the In+/In- of the regulator, and one at the Nodemcu. As for the regulator board not having a common ground, that may be part of the problem. The ground of the boards should all be connected together somehow.